# Find the least expense?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, triangle

You want to build a shop between three roads in the shape of an equilateral triangle.

> **What would be the best location for the shop so that you can reach each road with the minimum transportation cost?**

Obviously, it would be inside or on the triangular roads, but I need to know how you can find the best location?

Comment: Can you define transportation cost?  Is it the sum of distances to each road?

Comment: Surely it depends on the SHAPE of the shop to some degree? e.g. If it can be any shape, why not make it a triangle the exact shape and size of the space between all three roads, reducing your transportation costs effectively to zero??

Comment: @Stiv & JSi sorry I was not online at that time to give you reply and when I came back the question was already answered and that is the correct answer. I did not put up a lateral thinking tag. it was a logical knowledge base question. yes transportation cost means distance there you got it right JSI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming "transportation cost" means sum of distances to each of the three roads, and the side of the equilateral triangle has length $1$:

> You can build the store anywhere on or inside the triangle and the transportation cost will be $\sqrt{3}/2$.
>
>  [Here is the proof, called Viviani's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_theorem)
>
>  Note: I calculated the answer for a vertex, center of edge, and center of triangle and came up with the same answer each time.  So then I knew it had to be a trick question.  A bit of internet research led me to Viviani's theorem.

Comment: So I did indeed misread the question. Thanks for your answer. +1 (and also +1 to the question now)

Comment: @correct 

if per-pendiculars are drawn to the sides of an equilateral triangle from any point
in the triangle, their united length will be equal to the altitude of the triangle.